# Complex contour plot of a function of three complex variables

Tags: plotting

```
eqn[x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_, a1_, a2_] := 
  ((a1 + I a2) - (x2 + I y2))/(((x1 + I y1)(x2+ I y2)) - (a1 + I a2))
```

How can I plot the `eqn`? I need contour plot for different `a1 + I a2`.

I tried following:

```
 {ContourPlot[Re @ eqn[x1, y1, x2, y2, 3, 4], {x1, -1, 1}, {y1, -1, 1}, 
    PlotPoints -> 50], 
  ContourPlot[Im @ eqn[x1, y1, x2, y2, 3, 4], {x2, -1, 1}, {y2, -1, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {-0.5, 0.5}, PlotPoints -> 50]}
```

but failed to get something.

Comment: 1. Remove the underscores in your `ContourPlot[]` 2. You can only have two things varying at a time in `ContourPlot[]`, so you need to fix the other four parameters to certain values.

Comment: What you are asking for -- a complex contour plot of a function of three complex variables -- doesn't exist in _Mathematica_ (and AFAIK anywhere else).

Comment: Simply input the code from OP into a notebook and observe the different colors of `x1, y1` and `x2, y2` in the expressions within `ContourPlot`. Without specific numbers assigned to one or the other `eqn` does not evaluate to numbers and thus cannot be plotted. I guess this question will be closed as "arising due to a simple mistake".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on my comment,

> Without specific numbers assigned to one or the other `eqn` does not evaluate to numbers and thus cannot be plotted.

In my example I use a `Manipulate` to assign values to the otherwise undefined variables.

Most likely, you will find this as a suitable starting point:

```
{Manipulate[
  ContourPlot[Re@eqn[x1, y1, x2, y2, 3, 4], {x1, -1, 1}, {y1, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 50],
{x2, -1, 1}, {y2, -1, 1}],
 Manipulate[
  ContourPlot[Im@eqn[x1, y1, x2, y2, 3, 4], {x2, -1, 1}, {y2, -1, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {-0.5, 0.5}, PlotPoints -> 50],
{x1, -1, 1}, {y1, -1, 1}]}
```

> [image: Output]